# Update issues 16.04 - Failed to download repository information

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, updates, update-manager

I keep getting the old message that I experienced from previous upgrades of yonder.

Changing the server and refreshing doesn't seem to work anymore.

```
W:There is no public key available for the following key IDs: 1397BC53640DB551
W:Failed to fetch htt p://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.152 80]
W:Failed to fetch htt p://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-amd64/Packages 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.152 80]
W:Failed to fetch htt p://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.152 80]
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: run this from terminal `sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com  1397BC53640DB551`

Comment: Ok and then re-try the upgrade ?!